# Catch error from a function and use it accordingly in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I m using a npm package called 'steamid'.It throws a new error if ID isnt of the requested format.For example

```
if (isNaN(input)) {
        throw new Error("Unknown SteamID input format \"" + input + "\"");
}
```

for example a steam3ID is of format 'STEAM_0:0:202099338' every digits should run from 0-9.
If i give a input of 'STEAM_11:0:202099338'.
it throws a error.Telling-

```
Error: Unknown SteamID input format "STEAM_11:0:202099338"
```

I want to utilize this  error.If the error occurs i want to do something.

I tried this :

```
  const sid = new SteamID(requrl).on("error",function(err){
    console.log("from function",err);
  });
```

But this did not work.I m very new to coding and nodeJS in general any help would be serioulsy appriciated.THANK YOU

Comment: Suggest using `try { const sid = new SteamID() } catch (err) {}` pattern. [try...catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch)

Comment: i did.Dint work man.

Comment: Here is the code  ` try{
      const sid = new SteamID(requrl);
    }
    catch(err){
      console.log("from catch",err);
    }`

Comment: `try..catch` simply works. If your code isn't working, something else is wrong. More details are needed to diagnose what else is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical way to catch errors is with `try...catch` pattern:

```js
function throwsError() {
  throw new Error("this is a thrown error");
  return 42;
}

try {
  throwsError();
} catch (err) {
  console.log('err.message', err.message);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is wrap the function in another function using `try-catch`,

```
function createSteamID(input) {
  try {
    return { isError: false, data: new SteamID(input) }
  } catch (e) {
    return { isError: true, error: e}
  }

}
```

and when using it, check the value of `isError`